# Automatically Run Batch File After Debugging Stops in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, batch-file

I have an application I'm working on that involves creation of a lock file while in use.  Normally this works fine, but when running it in debug mode it can stop anywhere and not remove the lock file.  Is there a way to setup Visual Studio to automatically remove this lock file via a batch file after the debugging stop event has been triggered?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it one of two ways.  You can create a build event to delete all lock files.   Or you can add [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ae6e432%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For example:

```
#if DEBUG
    // add code to remove all existing lock files
    // when the program starts
#endif
```

Comment: I had wondered about that, but then wondered that if that would get in the way of testing the application's reaction to the lock file not being removed... of course I can always comment it out during that part of testing, but wondered if there would be a more slick way of approaching the issue.

Comment: ok... so if I use a preprocessor keyword like this I don't have access to the environment variables and objects to remove the file.  So any suggestions?

Comment: Does your application create the files?  If so, it should know where the files are to delete them.

Comment: The file is created in a referenced assembly using Environment.CurrentDirectory to keep it simple and relative.  This would need to delete it in a referencing assembly.  Though it should still be in the same directory, Environment.CurrentDirectory, nor Assembly reflection works in the preprocessor region.